# Dynamic groupings using IIF with multiple datasources

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm using report viewer and trying to create dynamic groupings on my table. Before the report is generated, I have a popup that ask if the report generated should be grouped by `category` or not.

I have two datasets, one called `ReportParameterDTO` and the second is called `LoanDTO`

The tablix is connected to the dataset `LoanDTO`. I want to create a parent grouping expression for that tablix such that if the first value of `ReportParameterDTO.GroupByCategory` is true, then it should group, otherwise do nothing.

What I tried

```
=IIF(First(Fields!GroupByCategory.Value, "ReportParameterDTO") = true, Fields!Category.Value, ""))
```

It gives me back and error around `Fields!GroupByCategory.Value` and the error within the error list states that A group expression for tablix includes an aggregate function.

The IIF Expression will compile if I use Field Values from `LoanDTO` but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new parameter.
2. Set it to Internal.
3. Set the Available Values to pull from the `ReportParameterDTO` dataset and the Value field will be `GroupByCategory`.
4. Also set the Default Values to pull from the `ReportParameterDTO` query.
5. Now you can refer to this internal parameter in your grouping expression like so:

   ```
   =IIf(Parameters!GroupByCategory.Value = True, Fields!Category.Value, Nothing)
   ```

Comment: Thank you, you hit two birds with one stone. I was wondering about the "nothing" part

Answer (score -1):

You can create both table and whit your parameter show or hide the table visibility. So like this I think is going to be more easy for you to set up your table and groups.

Comment: Why would I create two tables? I don't think you are understanding the problem.